# margin with flex wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to add some spacing between the divs using `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

The problem is that when I apply `margin-right` to the second item, the row breaks. How can I add some spacing between the items without breaking them in 2 rows?

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/ja6820vu/7/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
// Default
// ----------------------------------------------------
.collage {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.collage-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
  background: url("https://www.audi.co.uk/content/dam/audi/production/Models/NewModelsgallery/A5range/A5_Coupe/MY17/1920x1080_A5-Coupe-2016-side.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  &: nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  &:nth-child(1),
  &:nth-child(4) {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 50vw;
  }
}
// Button
// ----------------------------------------------------
 .btn {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="btn">View all 11 photos</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` will take care of paddings and borders but for margins you need to use `calc()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting the basis to `50%` then when you add the margin it push the next element since can't fit side by side anymore. You may want to let the items **grow** and avoid the basis:

```
.collage-item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

#### [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ja6820vu/8/)

Answer (score 2):

You have both second row images set to 50% width:

```
flex: 0 0 50%;
```

When you add the 16px horizontal margin, you exceed the total width of the row, forcing a wrap:

```
50% + 50% + 16px = overflow
```

Try factoring the margin space into the width of the images:

```
flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 8px);
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ja6820vu/9/)

Comment: Cool, both solutions works fine but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid those ugly &:nth-child() and add some spacing between the items.

Answer (score 2):

no need really to set a `width` (eventually a `min-width` and a `min-height` ), just tell the element to spray evenly via the short : `flex:1;` and also, `calc()` **will not be necessary**.

i added a last row of 3 to show the behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/ja6820vu/10/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.collage {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.collage-item {
  min-height: 17.5vw;
  min-width: 30%;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: url("https://www.audi.co.uk/content/dam/audi/production/Models/NewModelsgallery/A5range/A5_Coupe/MY17/1920x1080_A5-Coupe-2016-side.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1;
}
.collage-item:nth-child(1) {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.collage-item:nth-child(2), .collage-item:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
  height: 25vw;
}
.collage-item:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.collage-item:nth-child(4) {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.collage-item:nth-child(1), .collage-item:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 50vw;
}
.collage-item:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  background:url(http://www.comedywildlifephoto.com/images/gallery/0/00000150_t.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="collage-item"></div>
  <div class="btn">View all 11 photos</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove all of the nth-child selectors and set it to `min-width: 50%`, it till has the same issue that the OP is describing: the margin pushes it beyond 50% so there's only one per row