# Flex item when wrap, change margins and paddings

Tags: html, css

is there a way to change margin or padding when a flex item is wrapped?

This is my problem:

I have a div 'buy' with margin: 0 auto, because i want it to be always at the right, but when this div is wrapped, i want to change that margin.

**Before wrap:**

[image: Before wrap]

**After wrap:**

[image: After wrap]

This is my code:

HTML:

```css
.container {
  cursor: grab;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #24252A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #0d0d0d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#imgBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-top: 10px;
}   

#content {
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#buy {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy-specs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#buy > * {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container0" class="container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div id="imgBox">
        <img src="../img/pinguini.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Pinguini Tattici Nucleari</h2>
            <p id="luogo">Torino - Pala Alpitour</p><p>04/10/2021 | 21:00</p>
    </div>
    <div id="buy">
        <div class="buy-specs">
            <p>Prezzo: 39,10 €</p>
            <div id="quantityDiv"><p>Quantità: </p>
        </div>
        <button id="button0">Aggiungi al carrello</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What if you use `flex-grow: 1` instead of using margin, that way it's dynamic, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978400/margin-with-flex-wrap. Does that help?

Comment: I can use flex-grow: 1, but it has the same effect as margin. The div buy remains in the right position always

Comment: No. There is no CSS method of detecting when wrapping occurs

Comment: What is wrong about `flex-grow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach could be to let the middle one to grow and push the last one.

last one can receive : margin:auto to be centered if alone on its row:

possible example:

```css
.container {
  cursor: grab;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #24252A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #0d0d0d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#imgBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#buy {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:auto;/* optionnal to center if alone*/
}

.buy-specs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#buy>* {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container0" class="container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  <div id="imgBox">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/349&text=pinguini" alt="" draggable="false">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Pinguini Tattici Nucleari</h2>
    <p id="luogo">Torino - Pala Alpitour</p>
    <p>04/10/2021 | 21:00</p>
  </div>
  <div id="buy">
    <div class="buy-specs">
      <p>Prezzo: 39,10 €</p>
      <div id="quantityDiv">
        <p>Quantità: </p>
      </div>
      <button id="button0">Aggiungi al carrello</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that first an last one can be centered if standing alone on a row: